# Login Page using ASP.Net & Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax, authentication

I'm trying to make a login page using html, ajax & ASP.NET.The data is truly passed to the ajax function, but when I debug the asp page the username and password are sent with NULL.
The code is supposed to take username & password then returns the userid

Html page:

```
    <div id="usernameid">Username:</div><input id="username" type="text"/> <span id="username_status"></span>
    <div id="passwordid">Password:</div><input id="password" type="password"/> <span id="password_status"></span>
    <div> <input id="loginbutton" onclick="UserLogin()" type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function UserLogin() {
var postData = JSON.stringify({ "username": JSON.stringify($("#username").val()), "password": JSON.stringify($("#password").val()) });
alert(postData);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",

    url: "http://localhost:49317/LoginPageForLearn.aspx",
    data: postData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    success: callbackfunction,
    error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
    }); 
    }
    function callbackfunction(datacoming) {
    localStorage["UserID"] = datacoming;
    alert(datacoming);
```

Asp.net page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string userName = "";
        int userId = -1;
        string PassWord = "";
        if (Request.QueryString.Count != 0 && Request.QueryString["username"] != string.Empty && Request.QueryString["password"] != string.Empty)
            {
                userName = Request.QueryString["username"];
                PassWord = Request.QueryString["password"];
                userId = GetUserID(userName, PassWord);

            }
    }
```

Do you have any ideas why isn't the data passed correctly ? Or do you have any other ideas on how can I make a login page using html and access the data at SQL.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're sending a password in clear text through the QueryString? Are you considering security at all?

Comment: hmm, sorry I'm still learning.Do you have a better idea ?

Comment: Yes, use HTTPS. Also the POST verb is recommended to avoid getting the password in your web server logs.

Comment: Let the postback happen and use the event handler to authenticate. The approach you're using is just making it more complicated and less secure.

Comment: Thanks Darin & James!
I'm sorry coz I ask a lot.

Comment: @OnlyHope: No worries. That's what we're here for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a PageMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool MyMethod(string username, string password)
{
    ...
    return true;
}
```

and then get rid of the double JSON stringification and call the page method:

```
var postData = JSON.stringify({ 
    "username": $("#username").val(), 
    "password": $("#password").val() 
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "LoginPageForLearn.aspx/MyMethod",
    data: postData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: callbackfunction,
    error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
});
```

and in your callback you could test the result of the page method:

```
function callbackfunction(result) {
    if (result.d) {
        alert('success');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, excuse me would you please explain the usage of the webmethod ?

Comment: It's called PageMethod. It is a static method decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute that you define in your ASP.NET page and which could be invoked using an AJAX call and send JSON request to it. It basically allows you to expose some server side function to client scripting.

Comment: Aha,Ok ... 
Thanks a million
Will Try it now & see what happens :)

Comment: Ok, I know this is a stupid question, but what should I write at MyMethod ?

Comment: This will depend on what you want this method to do.

Comment: Should I just let it take the username and password and compare them to the ones at the database ?

Comment: Do you know why Request.QueryString is not accessible in the function?

Comment: because you are sending a POST request instead of GET and the parameters are sent in the POST body.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Thank you so so much & I'm really sorry for bothering a lot. You are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. You have to also return something in order to notify the client that the authentication succeeded or failed. You have to think about the programmatic work flow.

You can create a static method in the page that you're calling that returns a value in form of Bool or JSON. Something along these lines:

```
[WebMethod] 
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static bool Authenticate JsonMethod(int username, string password)
{ 
   bool isAuthenticated = // some method to authenticate
   return isAuthenticated;
}
```

Your AJAX would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:49317/LoginPageForLearn.aspx/Authenticate",
    data: postData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

In your success or failure call back, you'll assess from there on what you want to do with the returned value.

In any case, a handler would probably be better since it doesn't contain unnecessary mark up.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis .. Excuse me, would it be possible if you told me how the handler works ?

Comment: HttpHandlers are just end points and it responds to web requests. It includes IHttpHandler and IHttpModule interface among a few. Generic handlers ends with .ashx extension.

You can read more here -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx