# How do I do validation on modal bootstrap from a controller?

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a partial view login that uses modal bootstrap. After I have validated the model on the client side all worked fine. But I want to check if login fails, and if so, return an error message from the controller to modal bootstrap and not to the postback page. How can I do that?

**my _partialview login**:

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal"}))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align:right;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                }
    </div>
</div>
```

**Account Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you would like to get errors, show them to user without page reloading. All you need is to use some ajax and then using it's success/error functions show errors/redirect to new page. There are a lot of examples on stack too. Remember to use HTTPS for security reasons with password. Some example here: [Login Page using ASP.Net & Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998314/login-page-using-asp-net-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

You  should use some validation plugin for that. Here is Easiest and very popular Validation pugin [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Cheers!!